# ZEBRA ZT411 bad print size

Tags: zebra-printers, zpl

I have a ZEBRA ZT411 label printer. I had a 203dpi printhead and changed it to 300dpi. I installed the ZT411 300dpi ZPL driver. The printer is now incorrectly calibrating the label. It doesn't push it to the edge so I can tear it off, but it's still tucked inside. It only prints on the bottom of the label. In size 40mm. The size of the label is larger. I've tried everything. Where is the mistake of how this could be changed?

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

[image: 3]

Comment: If you have ZPL code with which you are printing that label, then you should post it, as apparently it was not written in a dpi-agnostic fashion. If you are using the printer as a general printer and printing from a Windows application, then probably see https://superuser.com/.

Comment: can you explain to me how to do it?

Comment: You normally need to recreate your label template for 300 dpi!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that's an issue with the label because in that case, you would only have a smaller printout, but no calibration issues.
If you change the printhead with a different resolution, you also need to replace the pulley and the belt because the amount of paper the printer will push when you print a 203 dpi label and a 300 dpi label, is different.
Check [here](https://www.zebra.com/content/dam/zebra_new_ia/en-us/solutions-verticals/product/Printer%20Parts/Industrial%20Printer%20Parts/ZT400%20Series/zt411-zt421-parts-catalog-en-us.pdf), page 2: you'll see the printhead part number (P1058930-013) which is the one you've used and the conversion kit (P1058930-022) which include the printhead, but also the mentioned pulley and belt, and that's the one you need.